# npm install fails due to "error: ‘class v8::ObjectTemplate’ has no member named ‘SetAccessCheckCallbacks"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I just got started on frontend development and followed different React tutorials which included instructions to configure the dependencies. I'm quite overwhelmed by the mass of boilerplate files which are necessary to produce a simple "Hello world!" project.Now, I'm stuck for hours with

```
> npm install
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/1627/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> contextify@0.1.15 install /home/richter/mereet/mereet-frontend/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Verzeichnis „/home/richter/mereet/mereet-frontend/node_modules/contextify/build“ wird betreten
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
In file included from ../src/contextify.cc:3:
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::AsyncQueueWorker(Nan::AsyncWorker*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:2232:62: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
     , reinterpret_cast<uv_after_work_cb>(AsyncExecuteComplete)
                                                              ^
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE ContextifyContext::New(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/contextify.cc:62:74: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         ContextifyContext* ctx = new ContextifyContext(info[0]->ToObject());
                                                                          ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10254:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE ContextifyContext::Run(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/contextify.cc:77:48: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Local<String> code = info[0]->ToString();
                                                ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10248:15: note: declared here
 Local<String> Value::ToString() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc:83:51: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             ScriptOrigin origin(info[1]->ToString());
                                                   ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10248:15: note: declared here
 Local<String> Value::ToString() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Context> ContextWrap::createV8Context(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’:
../src/contextify.cc:131:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Function::NewInstance()’
         Local<Object> wrapper = Nan::New(constructor)->NewInstance();
                                                                    ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:4105:44: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Function::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> NewInstance(
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:4105:44: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:4108:44: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Function::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> NewInstance(
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:4108:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../src/contextify.cc:150:16: error: ‘class v8::ObjectTemplate’ has no member named ‘SetAccessCheckCallbacks’; did you mean ‘SetAccessCheckCallback’?
         otmpl->SetAccessCheckCallbacks(GlobalPropertyNamedAccessCheck,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                SetAccessCheckCallback
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static void ContextWrap::GlobalPropertyGetter(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
../src/contextify.cc:176:52: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Local<Object> data = info.Data()->ToObject();
                                                    ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10254:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc:182:80: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::GetRealNamedProperty(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
         Local<Value> rv = Nan::New(ctx->sandbox)->GetRealNamedProperty(property);
                                                                                ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:3668:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::GetRealNamedProperty(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Name>)’
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> GetRealNamedProperty(
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:3668:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static void ContextWrap::GlobalPropertySetter(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
../src/contextify.cc:192:52: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Local<Object> data = info.Data()->ToObject();
                                                    ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10254:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static void ContextWrap::GlobalPropertyQuery(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Integer>&)’:
../src/contextify.cc:203:52: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Local<Object> data = info.Data()->ToObject();
                                                    ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10254:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc:209:67: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::GetRealNamedProperty(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
         if (!Nan::New(ctx->sandbox)->GetRealNamedProperty(property).IsEmpty() ||
                                                                   ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:3668:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::GetRealNamedProperty(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Name>)’
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> GetRealNamedProperty(
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:3668:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/contextify.cc:210:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::GetRealNamedProperty(v8::Local<v8::String>&)’
             !Nan::New(ctx->proxyGlobal)->GetRealNamedProperty(property).IsEmpty()) {
                                                                       ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:3668:43: note: candidate: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::GetRealNamedProperty(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Name>)’
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> GetRealNamedProperty(
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:3668:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static void ContextWrap::GlobalPropertyDeleter(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Boolean>&)’:
../src/contextify.cc:218:52: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Local<Object> data = info.Data()->ToObject();
                                                    ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10254:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc:224:63: warning: ‘bool v8::Object::Delete(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         bool success = Nan::New(ctx->sandbox)->Delete(property);
                                                               ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:26,
                 from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:3442:43: note: declared here
   V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version", bool Delete(Local<Value> key));
                                           ^~~~~~
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^~~~~~~~~~
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static void ContextWrap::GlobalPropertyEnumerator(const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Array>&)’:
../src/contextify.cc:229:52: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Local<Object> data = info.Data()->ToObject();
                                                    ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10254:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE ContextifyScript::New(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/contextify.cc:286:48: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Local<String> code = info[0]->ToString();
                                                ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10248:15: note: declared here
 Local<String> Value::ToString() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc:291:52: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::String> v8::Value::ToString() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                ? info[1]->ToString()
                                                    ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10248:15: note: declared here
 Local<String> Value::ToString() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE ContextifyScript::RunInContext(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../src/contextify.cc:319:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         if (!ContextifyContext::InstanceOf(info[0]->ToObject()))
                                                              ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10254:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^~~~~
../src/contextify.cc:322:95: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject() const’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         ContextifyContext* ctx = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<ContextifyContext>(info[0]->ToObject());
                                                                                               ^
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:10254:15: note: declared here
 Local<Object> Value::ToObject() const {
               ^~~~~
In file included from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
../src/contextify.cc: At global scope:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:495:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’ to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
                                           ^
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:529:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/contextify.cc:361:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
     NODE_MODULE(contextify, init)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = node::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:85:78:   required from here
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:9707:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
                reinterpret_cast<Callback>(callback), type);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = Nan::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:66:61:   required from here
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:9707:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2718,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_weak.h: In instantiation of ‘Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::WeakCallbackInfo(Nan::Persistent<v8::Value>*, Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, void*, void*, void*) [with T = ContextWrap; Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<ContextWrap>&)]’:
../../nan/nan_weak.h:264:12:   required from ‘void Nan::Persistent<T, M>::SetWeak(P*, typename Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, Nan::WeakCallbackType) [with P = ContextWrap; T = v8::Object; M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>; typename Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<ContextWrap>&); Nan::WeakCallbackType = v8::WeakCallbackType]’
../src/contextify.cc:136:132:   required from here
../../nan/nan_weak.h:58:16: warning: ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’ writing to an object of type ‘class v8::Persistent<v8::Value>’ with no trivial copy-assignment; use copy-assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
     std::memcpy(&persistent_, persistent, sizeof (v8::Persistent<v8::Value>));
     ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:784:35: note: ‘class v8::Persistent<v8::Value>’ declared here
 template <class T, class M> class Persistent : public PersistentBase<T> {
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<ContextWrap>; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<ContextWrap> >&)]’:
../../nan/nan_weak.h:268:35:   required from ‘void Nan::Persistent<T, M>::SetWeak(P*, typename Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, Nan::WeakCallbackType) [with P = ContextWrap; T = v8::Object; M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>; typename Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<ContextWrap>&); Nan::WeakCallbackType = v8::WeakCallbackType]’
../src/contextify.cc:136:132:   required from here
/home/richter/.node-gyp/11.9.0/include/node/v8.h:9707:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<ContextWrap> >::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::WeakCallbackInfo<ContextWrap> >&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
                reinterpret_cast<Callback>(callback), type);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [contextify.target.mk:101: Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o] Fehler 1
make: Verzeichnis „/home/richter/mereet/mereet-frontend/node_modules/contextify/build“ wird verlassen
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-15-generic
gyp ERR! command "/snap/node/1627/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/richter/mereet/mereet-frontend/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v11.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 (node_modules/contextify):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

audited 35891 packages in 16.281s
found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

which I get on Ubuntu 18.10 with an up-to-date installation of NodeJS through `snap` as well as on the Docker image `node:11-slim`.

My research goes as far as figuring out that `contextify` is obsolete because it is already contained in NodeJS. However, I see no connection to this very obscure error.

Due to the relatively high rate of outdated code and whole projects in the "frontend world" (I have a Java backend background), I'm interested in both fixing this issue and a general approach to solving this kind of dependency problems - I fear that solving this specific case will just forward me to the next issue which has been my weekend so far getting started on frontend development.

My search for existing questions and posts outside SO yields a ton of "class ... has no member named", but I can't extract any steps to take from them.

Comment: Same issue here; `‘class Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘IsNearDeath’` is my specific message.